# Keycloak gatekeeper updates token but does not add it to request

Tags: token, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

Where do I need to send a request to have access token updated? Because if I send a request to my resource service I have token expired exception even if gatekeeper updates the token.

I want to update an access token using a refresh token. The gatekeeper documentations says 'If a request for an access token contains a refresh token and --enable-refresh-tokens is set to true, the proxy will automatically refresh the access token for you.' - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#refresh-tokens

And indeed when token is expired gatekeeper updates access token and injects it somewhere in the response, but when the request is forwarded to the resource service I have ExpiredJwtException, because there is no new refreshed token in the request.
And I can see in failed response that there is an old token instead of new one.
However if a timeout error occurs on the resource service side and gatekeeper returns its own response to user than I can see that access and refresh tokens are updated.

Here is the gatekeeper logs:

```
1.5732098220167706e+09  info    keycloak-gatekeeper/middleware.go:154   accces token for user has expired, attemping to refresh the token   {"client_ip": "172.18.0.1:36270", "email": "demo@demo1.com"}
1.5732098220504465e+09  info    keycloak-gatekeeper/middleware.go:206   injecting the refreshed access token cookie {"client_ip": "172.18.0.1:36270", "cookie_name": "kc-access", "email": "demo@demo1.com", "refresh_expires_in": 3600, "expires_in": 59.949554727}
1.573209822050499e+09   debug   keycloak-gatekeeper/middleware.go:226   renew refresh cookie with new refresh token {"refresh_expires_in": 3600}
1.5732098220505428e+09  debug   keycloak-gatekeeper/middleware.go:367   access permitted to resource    {"access": "permitted", "email": "demo@demo1.com", "expires": -5.050542554, "resource": "/*"}
1.573209851051063e+09   info    keycloak-gatekeeper/middleware.go:90    client request  {"latency": 29.036757293, "status": 500, "bytes": 44, "client_ip": "172.18.0.1:36270", "method": "GET", "path": "/ping"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token is stored encrypted in the `kc-state` cookie which is in the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header. To forward this request you need to add the `kc-state` parameter to the `Cookie` HTTP header.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: kc-state=blabla
Set-Cookie: another-cookie=yadada

GET /sample_page.html HTTP/2.0
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: kc-state=blabla; another-cookie=yadada
```

If you have a frontend the `Cookie` header will be added automatically.